# SharedPreferences передача значений

Tags: java, android

Хочу передать значение между диалогом и фрагментом, сохраняю так

```
setNumbers(view.getContext(), holder.mBoundString);

public static String setNumbers(Context context, String numbers) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
    .putString(PREF_NUMB_NUMBERS, numbers).apply();

    Log.i(PREF_NUMB_NUMBERS, "QueryTextSubmit: " + numbers);
    return numbers;
}
```

При

```
String numbers = NumbSheetDialogView.setNumbers(getActivity(), "1");
```

Значение не приходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(PREF_NUMB_NUMBERS, "DEFAULT_VALUE"));
```

Comment: я не знаю в чем дело пишу     String numbers =  NumbSheetDialogView.setNumbers(getActivity(), "1"); Значение не приходит, моет я не там вызываю ? онкрейтвю

Comment: спасибо так работает . Но можно ли по моему методу как нить получить

Comment: как мне проверить что значение обновилось?

Comment: @Артем, не понял в чём у вас проблема.

Comment: как мне проверить текущ значение  `PREF_NUMB_NUMBERS` и сравнить его с текущим `PREF_NUMB_NUMBERS`, поменялось ли оно

Comment: @Артем, PREF_NUMB_NUMBERS должно быть строковой статической финальной константой и не должно никогда меняться.

Comment: @Артем, если мой ответ отвечает на изначальный вопрос о получении значения - отметьте его верным. Если есть ещё вопросы - задавацте новый вопрос. Один вопрос - один ответ.